# Validation with callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, callback, rails-activerecord

I want to validate that there's always at least one user with the role `moderator` in my application.

I have two callbacks and a method:

```
before_save    :ensure_one_moderator_always_present, if: :role_changed?
before_destroy :ensure_one_moderator_always_present

def ensure_one_moderator_always_present
  if all_active_moderators.where.not(id: self.id).size =< 1
    errors.add(:content, "There always needs to be at least one manager.")
  end
end
```

I thought adding error message like I do in the method above would stop the transaction exactly like in validation, but it doesn't.

What am I doing wrong/how should I accomplish the above?

Answer (score 0):

return false after `errors.add` else true

```
def ensure_one_moderator_always_present
  if all_active_moderators.where.not(id: self.id).size =< 1
    errors.add(:content, "There always needs to be at least one manager.")
    false
  end
  true
end
```